# Not able to access app deployed on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-registry, azure-aks

I am getting following error while accessing the app deployed on Azure kubernetes service

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {},
  "code": 403
}
```

I have followed all steps as given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app

I know that this is something to do with authentication and RBAC, but i don't know what exactly is wrong and where should i make changes.

Comment: Are you connecting from a client without using any certificates?

Comment: @NicolaBen I am connecting from the browser. the app is a basic nodejs server. Regarding the certificates, i don't have any idea where should i configure them

Comment: Which step do you get the error?

Comment: could you provide your `Service` and `Ingress` manifests?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT The app is deployed successfully. I get error while accessing the app simplegrap-agh-rgp-bangalor-ae1cfc-fac72fa1.hcp.southeastasia.azmk8s.io
This is my deployment file https://gist.github.com/preetb123/d5f895d9505e79e2d5d077f47e1f9bb2

Comment: If the image works well and can access locally. Now you should check the load balancer or ingress which you use and if your service is on work.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT It works fine when run on local kubernetes cluster on my machine. only when it is deployed to AKS, i get this error.

Comment: Do you check if you access the right port and address?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT yes. gist.github.com/preetb123/d5f895d9505e79e2d5d077f47e1f9bb2. It has something to do with RBAC. There is some info here, but i don't understand how to integrate this in the project. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal. Really stuck on this for many days.

Comment: This is the authentication for the registry when you pull or push the image. If you want to use it when you create pod from the image in the registry you can read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks).

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I am able to successfully push the image to the ACR, create AKS and deploy the app. I can see deployments created and also the 3 nodes running but can't access the app
    $ kubectl get deployments
     NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
     gql-server-deployment   3         4         1            3           4d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app) you posted. You will be successful in finishing that. The destination of each step below:

1. Create the image and make sure it can work without any error.
2. Create an Azure Container Registry and push the image into the registry.
3. Create a Service Principal for the AKS to let it just can pull the image from the registry.
4. Change the yaml file and make it pull the image from the Azure Registry, then crate pods in the AKS nodes.

You just need these four steps to run the application on AKS. Then get the IP address through the command `kubectl get service azure-vote-front --watch` like the step 4. If you can not access the application, check your steps carefully again.

Also, you can check all the pods status through the command `kubectl describe pods` or one pod with `kubectl describe pod podName`.

**Update**

I test with the image you provide and the result here:

[image]

And you can get the service information and know which port you should use to browse.

[image]

Comment: I have followed all the steps in exactly the same manner as given in the article. Also, the same steps are given in the course https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/azure-container-service-big-picture, and i did the same.

Comment: @Preetam All steps work well for you. Maybe the problem is in your image. Do you mind providing the image for the test?

Comment: @Preetam I think there may be something wrong with the port you expose. You can check the info with the command `kubectl describe services gql-server-service`.

Comment: I have uploaded the image to docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/preetb123/simple-graphql-server/ the app is exposed at port 4000

Comment: I cannot pull the image. Do you try it?

Comment: use this: docker pull preetb123/simple-graphql-server:v1

Comment: using extenal-ip with port works(although i didn't try it before, i tried just with ip and not ip:port. With just IP i was getting connection timeout), but i want it to work with api-server-address that appears in the aks cluster on azure portal as given in the image https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4496555/45680275-28279900-bb58-11e8-8a31-ea0d4646389b.png

Comment: @Preetam That is the API server addess. Not that you would use to browse. Find the real resource group that the Azure Kuberbetes Cluster nodes in. The group name should be MC_aksGroupName_aksName_location.